# Error switching layout to API19 (Android 4.4.2)

Tags: visual-studio, android-layout, xamarin.android

I have googled for a while and any of the solutions worked for me. My problem is when i try to change a layout to API version 19, throws me this error:

> mono.android.DesignerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:46)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.checkRenderResultForError(DesignerSession.java:187)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:239)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:702)
>       at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
>       at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.disposeSystem(Resources_Delegate.java:85)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.disposeResources(BridgeContext.java:264)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.tearDown(RenderAction.java:257)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.release(RenderAction.java:220)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:438)
>       at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:233)
>       ... 4 more

This is the Main.axml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:gridSpec="1|8|#0093eeff|K:#ee8700ff:16,l:72,l:16,r|S:#83ee00ff:16,0,l:16,56,l:16,0,r"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <Button
        android:text="Hello world"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="259.5dp"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:onClick="btnOneClick" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to install extras, tools and API 19 from the SDK manager, but nothing is working. Know someone why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same error, and I found [this thread here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92892/designer-suddenly-stops-working-for-one-project) which helped me.
OlafB posted a response about halfway down that helped me:

> I changed the application to another API level and it now displays
>   correctly in the Designer. Not sure what the problem was / is.
>
> I had the 'Compile using Android version' set to API 19. When I
>   changed it to Android 6.0, the designer works, even though the Minimum
>   Android Version and Targeted Android Version are still API 19 (Android
>   4.4.2).

The option that he's talking about changing is the **Compile using Android version: (Target Framework)** setting on the Application tab in the project properties.
The other settings he's talking about are in the "Android Manifest" section of the properties.
In my case, I changed the "Compile using..." setting to Android 4.1 since that's the version I'm currently testing.